# How to check if there is any content in a variable(A variable containing dynamic SQL formula values) declared inside a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this below code which is perfectly executing fine for non-null values but if I get any Null values the variable '@FORMULA' doesnt display anything in the debug mode and even if I include a NULL check validation its not executing and I'm getting wrong values.

Is there any way to overcome the effect of null values in this condition ?

```
CREATE TABLE #MathLogicExecution 
(
    IDNUM INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
    Expression VARCHAR(256)
)

BEGIN
    SELECT @ig =1

    WHILE @ig <= @INPUTCOUNT
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #MathLogicExecution
            SELECT 
                REPLACE(@FORMULA, ATTRIBUTENAME, INPUTVALUES) 
            FROM #MathLogicTable 
            WHERE IDNUM = @ig

        SET @FORMULA = (SELECT Expression FROM #MathLogicExecution  
                        WHERE IDNUM = @ig)
        SET @ig = @ig + 1
    END
END

IF (@FORMULA = NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @iv = @iv + 1
    DROP TABLE #MathLogicTable
    DROP TABLE #BusinesLogicIDTabe
    CONTINUE
END
```

Comment: Try IS NULL istead of = NULL

Comment: In MS SQL you cannot compare NULLs using the "=" operator.  it will always return false (NULL = NULL yields false). you need to use either IS NULL or IS NOT NULL. I haven't try this in other SQL systems.

Comment: @NPToita The equation NULL = NULL yields NULL.

Comment: @TT. that may be true, but the boolean evaluation of NULL yields false.

Comment: @NPToita By that reasoning `NOT(NULL=NULL)` would yield `TRUE` which is not the case. `NULL=NULL` effectively yields `NULL`. You cannot compare if there is nothing to compare with.

Comment: @NPToita For reference read this on [`ANSI_NULLS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)

Comment: Actually the domain is `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `UNKNOWN`. So `NULL=NULL` and `NULL<>NULL` yields `UNKNOWN`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TT. I wasn't saying NOT(NULL = NULL) would yield true. I was just saying to SQL a null condition would yield false. UNKNOWN is yields false.

Comment: @NPToita That is incorrect. Read this [TN on NULL Values](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on how logic applies to NULL values. To quote: `Comparisons between two null values, or between a NULL and any other value, return **unknown** because the value of each NULL is unknown.`.

Comment: @TT. I'm not saying you're wrong either. All I'm saying is that if your condition results in a NULL or UNKNOWN, the final result of the condition is false. We were talking about two different things here.

Comment: @NPToita I'm sorry sir, if a TN from the creators of SQL Server doesn't convince you then nothing will. The comparison doesn't yield false, it yields unknown. All you can say about it is that it yields something that isn't true. That is totally different than saying that it yields false.

Comment: @TT. Okay, I get what you tried to say. you win because I wasn't able to get you to understand what I was trying to say. Me <<<< Bad at communications. case closed.

Comment: @NPToita It isn't about winning, I was trying to get the idea of Three-Valued Logic (3VL) accross, which is essentially different than Boolean Logic (2VL). Understanding this is crucial to handling NULLs correctly in SQL Server (or any other RDMS). The 3VL adds the logical value `UNKNOWN`, so the domain has 3 logical values. A 3VL expression can therefore result in `UNKNOWN`. A good read on this [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/). I hope you and the OP haven't lost their hair by now :)

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen.... Thanks it got Worked... Thanks for the comments guys....